# Oracle select count throws ORA-00600, join tables limited only to 5 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00600

I am having an issue with oracle database.

```
SELECT COUNT(A.A) AS count
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.B = B.B
LEFT JOIN C ON A.C = C.C
LEFT JOIN D ON A.D = D.D
LEFT JOIN E ON A.E = E.E
-- Limit is here
LEFT JOIN F ON A.F = F.F
LEFT JOIN G ON A.G = G.G
LEFT JOIN H ON A.H = H.H
LEFT JOIN I ON A.I = I.I
LEFT JOIN J ON A.J = J.J
```

I try to execute a query similar to query above, but it always return ORA-00600 Exception.
So i try to limit the table joining, and it works well when i stopped joining at table E, but when i hit more tables, it shows the exception again.

I've never encountered something like this when using SQLServer. I used to join more than 20 tables when using SQLServer. Is this a bug in oracle?

Comment: Your join is probably producing an inordinate amount of rows.  I'm guessing that you would have the same problem on SQL Server if you had the same data.

Comment: ORA-0600 is an internal error (you do not show the details), which requires support from Oracle.  It does not mean you cannot join > 5 tables.

Comment: ORA-0600 will normally require passing to Oracle support to resolve. You can find some clues sometimes by looking at the full message in the alert log and searching KnowledgeBase.

Comment: If this is analogous to your actual query then it's equivalent to `select count(a) from a`, no need for the extra tables... Assuming it's not we'd need a reproducible example in order to be able to help at all. As other's have said it's likely that this is an Oracle bug. You can definitely join more than 5 tables.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Oracle support must be called to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why do you suspect that the **number** of tables in the join is the issue? Why not, for example, something specific about table `F`? Did you try to bypass it and join directly to `G`, and if you did, did you see the same error? Also, are all those tables or are some of them views?